# Why two threads when I only call the ExecutorService.execute() once?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class ExceptionThread2 implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println("run() by " + t);
    System.out.println(
      "eh = " + t.getUncaughtExceptionHandler());
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}

class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("caught " + e);
  }
}

class HandlerThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
  public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    System.out.println(this + " creating new Thread");
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    System.out.println("created " + t);
    t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
      new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
    System.out.println(
      "eh = " + t.getUncaughtExceptionHandler());
    return t;
  }
}

public class CaptureUncaughtException {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(
      new HandlerThreadFactory());
    exec.execute(new ExceptionThread2());
  }
}
```

According to Thinking in Java(4 Edition),the result would be:

```
HandlerThreadFactory@de6ced creating new Thread
created Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
eh = MyUncaughtExceptionHandler@1fb8ee3
run() by Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
eh = MyUncaughtExceptionHandler@1fb8ee3
caught java.lang.RuntimeException
```

but on my machine, the result was:

```
HandlerThreadFactory@2e9e53ed creating new Thread
created Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
eh = MyUncaughtExceptionHandler@2fdb8f3a
run() by Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
eh = MyUncaughtExceptionHandler@2fdb8f3a
HandlerThreadFactory@2e9e53ed creating new Thread
created Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
eh = MyUncaughtExceptionHandler@22b1656f
caught java.lang.RuntimeException
```

I cannot figure out where is the [Thread-1,5,main] come from?

PS: The only difference was that the former used Java SE5, but I used Java SE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to look into the implementation, but it creates two threads because it attempts to have at least 1 thread running at all times.

The reason its slightly confusing is because of the sequence in which this happens. Handling worker death (such as those caused by an uncaught exception) happens as the final act before the thread actually dies. This means the sequence of operations is

- create worker and schedule runnable (`HandlerThreadFactory.newThread(r)`)

  - Thread-0 lives
- error thrown (`ExceptionThread2.run()`)

  - Thread-0 lives
- worker marked dead (`ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker` finally block)

  - Thread-0 lives
- potentially create new worker (`HandlerThreadFactory.newThread(r)`)

  - Thread-0 lives
  - Thread-1 lives
- let exception bubble up to the uncaught exception handler (`MyUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException`)

  - Thread-0 dead
  - Thread-1 lives

If your book is correct that means the implementation has changed since it was written. Probably since a cached threadpool usually has quite a volatile workload, so keeping threads running makes it more efficient.

Comment: Note that it only recreates the thread if it terminated abruptly.